# password saving system for my iOS Webview Application

Tags: ios, webview

I use Web2App template by Sherdleapps.  It works good for me.  But, the way I setup the tabs is as follows.  Each tab leads to a different page on a certain website.  The certain website requires a login no matter what page your on.  if you are on a normal web browser, you input your password once, and you can access any page. But on this app I have to input my password on every tab.  So essentially I have to put in a password 5 times to get to the app to full functionality where I just swipe over to access different pages.  I need help, 1stly, adding a feature which I know is possible where i Input the password on one page, and it is the shared between all.  And it if is possible, a password caching system.

Comment: I will submit the zip file when needed

Comment: Try to post code what you tried so far

Comment: I haven't tried any code yet.  I have no clue what Im working on.  I can submit the xip file.  BTW its for ios.